# How to make image field larger?

Tags: python, odoo

At **asset** module we have **'asset.asset'** field there I have **'image_medium'**. So I wanted to make it larger .Below I have done that field larger **128px * 128px** but after saving its blurred I mean I wanted to have it on higher pixels.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Change field name `'image_medium'` to `image` in xml view.
Remove class `oe_avatar` and add `height="300" width="300"`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```xml
<field name="image"  widget="image" class="oe_right oe_image_custom" style="width: 265px; height: 300px;"/>
```

Comment: k the what i should add at .py field file

Answer (score 0):

This is example of image small, medium and logo type

```
_columns = {
    'brand_id': fields.many2one('model.name', 'Make', required=True),
    'image': fields.related('brand_id', 'image', type="binary", string="Logo"),
    'image_medium': fields.related('brand_id', 'image_medium', type="binary", string="Logo (medium)"),
    'image_small': fields.related('brand_id', 'image_small', type="binary", string="Logo (small)"),
}
```

and for new api you can do the following code:

```
# image: all image fields are base64 encoded and PIL-supported
image = openerp.fields.Binary("Photo", attachment=True,
    help="This field holds the image used as photo for the employee, limited to 1024x1024px.")
image_medium = openerp.fields.Binary("Medium-sized photo",
    compute='_compute_images', inverse='_inverse_image_medium', store=True, attachment=True,
    help="Medium-sized photo of the employee. It is automatically "\
         "resized as a 128x128px image, with aspect ratio preserved. "\
         "Use this field in form views or some kanban views.")
image_small = openerp.fields.Binary("Small-sized photo",
    compute='_compute_images', inverse='_inverse_image_small', store=True, attachment=True,
    help="Small-sized photo of the employee. It is automatically "\
         "resized as a 64x64px image, with aspect ratio preserved. "\
         "Use this field anywhere a small image is required.")

@api.depends('image')
def _compute_images(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.image_medium = tools.image_resize_image_medium(rec.image)
        rec.image_small = tools.image_resize_image_small(rec.image)

def _inverse_image_medium(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.image = tools.image_resize_image_big(rec.image_medium)

def _inverse_image_small(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.image = tools.image_resize_image_big(rec.image_small)

def _get_default_image(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    image_path = get_module_resource('hr', 'static/src/img', 'default_image.png')
    return tools.image_resize_image_big(open(image_path, 'rb').read().encode('base64'))
```